# Java second variable dismisses first one

Tags: java, swing, variables, awt, jprogressbar

What I have to do is make a little GUI that when a `button` is clicked it starts to progress bars with `threads`; however, we have to do it with an inner class that implements the `Runnable interface`, and within the constructor for that class, it takes a `String` and a `JProgressBar` object. Then within the main constructor, we are supposed to instantiate 2 `JProgressBar` objects and then create 2 of the Inner class objects using those `JProgressBars`.

Only my second `JProgressBar` is updating with the `thread`. I know that my second `JProgressBar` is basically overriding my first one, but I don't know how I would go to fix that, because if I try to change the inner class's constructor to setting 2 `JProgressBar` attributes equal to the parameter of the constructor, then the first `JProgessBar` just completely disappears from the GUI. Here is my code, thank you to anyone that can help.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Lab4Part2 {
    //Attributes
    private JFrame frame;
    private String progress;
    private JProgressBar jpb;

    //Constructor
    public Lab4Part2() {
      //Create frame with specified grid layout
      frame = new JFrame();
      GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0,1);
      frame.setLayout(grid);
      JButton jbClick = new JButton("Let's start this show");
      frame.add(jbClick);

      //Add in JProgressBars and create Inner Class objects with them
      JProgressBar jpb1 = new JProgressBar();
      JProgressBar jpb2 = new JProgressBar();
      InnerProgress bar1 = new InnerProgress("Progress 1: ", jpb1);
      InnerProgress bar2 = new InnerProgress("Progress 2: ", jpb2);

      //Anonymous class for the button's action listener
      jbClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(bar1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(bar2);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
         }
      });

      //Adds inner object to frame
      frame.add(bar1);
      frame.add(bar2);

      //Packing and stuff
      frame.pack();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

      //Inner class
      class InnerProgress extends JPanel implements Runnable {

      //Constructor
      public InnerProgress(String pbar, JProgressBar jpBar) {
         jpBar.setMinimum(0);
         jpBar.setMaximum(80);
         jpBar.setStringPainted(true);
         progress = pbar;
         jpb = jpBar;
         JLabel label = new JLabel(pbar);
         add(label);
         add(jpBar);
      }

      //Thread action
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("We are running " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
         for(int i = 1; i<= 80; i++) {
            try {
               Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)Math.random()*100);
               jpb.setValue(i);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie) {
               System.out.println(ie);
            }
         }
         System.out.println("Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
     }

      //Main
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Lab4Part2();
     }

    }
```

Comment: Your inner class should have it's own reference to the progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner class should maintain it's own reference to the `JProgressBar` that it is passed.

Simply take...

```
private JProgressBar jpb;
```

and move it inside your inner class

```
class InnerProgress extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private JProgressBar jpb;
    //...
```

So, two other issues

One, `(long)Math.random()*100` is causing the result of `Math.random()` to be case to an `int`, which will result in it becoming `0`.

You need to cast the result of the operation, for example...

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep((int)(Math.random() * 500));
```

*(nb: I made it 500 for my testing)*

Two, Swing is not thread safe.  This means you should not be updating the UI from outside of the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

So, instead of...

```
jpb.setValue(i);
```

I wrote a new method which will update the UI accordingly

```
protected void updateProgress(int value) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InnerProgress.this.jpb.setValue(value);
        }
    });
}
```

*(Long and short, this over comes issues with referencing variables from inside an anonymous context)*

Then simply called it using `updateProgress(i);`

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Lab4Part2 {
//Attributes

    private JFrame frame;
    private String progress;

//Constructor
    public Lab4Part2() {
        //Create frame with specified grid layout
        frame = new JFrame();
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0, 1);
        frame.setLayout(grid);
        JButton jbClick = new JButton("Let's start this show");
        frame.add(jbClick);

        //Add in JProgressBars and create Inner Class objects with them
        JProgressBar jpb1 = new JProgressBar();
        JProgressBar jpb2 = new JProgressBar();
        InnerProgress bar1 = new InnerProgress("Progress 1: ", jpb1);
        InnerProgress bar2 = new InnerProgress("Progress 2: ", jpb2);

        //Anonymous class for the button's action listener
        jbClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Thread t1 = new Thread(bar1);
                Thread t2 = new Thread(bar2);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
            }
        });

        //Adds inner object to frame
        frame.add(bar1);
        frame.add(bar2);

        //Packing and stuff
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Inner class
    class InnerProgress extends JPanel implements Runnable {

        private JProgressBar jpb;

        //Constructor
        public InnerProgress(String pbar, JProgressBar jpBar) {
            jpBar.setMinimum(0);
            jpBar.setMaximum(80);
            jpBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progress = pbar;
            jpb = jpBar;
            JLabel label = new JLabel(pbar);
            add(label);
            add(jpBar);
        }

        //Thread action
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("We are running " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for (int i = 1; i <= 80; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep((int)(Math.random() * 500));
                    updateProgress(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    System.out.println(ie);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

    protected void updateProgress(int value) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InnerProgress.this.jpb.setValue(value);
            }
        });
    }
    }

    //Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Lab4Part2();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I just stressed myself out too much, and what you did easily worked. I was able to see why too, just a silly mistake by me really, but I couldn't understand it at the time. But now seeing it, I feel so dumb lol. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees 